# NotImplementedError (Use a queueing backend...) using delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, queue, delayed-job

In my Rails app (4.2.4), I have been trying to get asynchronous mail sending to work.

I installed delayed_job as my queue adapter, and set it as the adapter in several places: config/application.rb, config/environments/{development,production}.rb, and config/initializers/active_job.rb.

**Installation:**

I added this to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

Then, I ran the following commands:

```
$ bundle install
$ rails generate delayed_job:active_record
$ rake db:migrate
$ bin/delayed_job start
```

In config/application.rb, config/environments/production.rb, config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

In config/initializers/active_job.rb (added when the above did not work):

```
ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

I've also run an ActiveRecord migration for delayed_job, and started bin/delayed_job before running my server.

**That being said, any time I try:**

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later(wait: 1.minutes)
```

I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError (Use a queueing backend to enqueue jobs in the
future. Read more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html):
    app/controllers/user_controller.rb:25:in `create'
    config.ru:25:in `call'
```

I was under the impression that delayed_job is a queueing backend... am I missing something?

EDIT:

I can't get sucker_punch to work either. When installing sucker_punch in the bundler, and using:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sucker_punch
```

in config/application.rb, I get the same error and stack trace.

Comment: Could you expand on how you installed delayed_job exactly?

Comment: Sure. First, I installed the gem:

    `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'`, `bundle install`

Then, ran:

    `rails generate delayed_job:active_record`,
    `rake db:migrate`,
    `bin/delayed_job start`,
    `rails server`

Comment: What about `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job` in *application.rb*, you said something about the environment files too. What did you put in the initializer? Please update your answer, so other readers have all the information.

Comment: Yeah, I put that line in config/application.rb, config/environments/production.rb (the environment I'm using), and config/environments/development.rb (in case I was using the wrong environment). I'll update it now

Comment: `application.rb` is enough, no need for each environment if it's there. And let's fix delayed_job before you setup *sucker_punch*.

Comment: Right, initially that was the only place I put it. I placed it everywhere else when I ran into the error. Also: I updated the question, should be more comprehensive now

Comment: My final comment: have you restarted the server?

Comment: Several times, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide you are following all the steps listed [here](http://blog.xebia.in/2015/04/14/asynchronous-mails-in-rails-4/), I feel you didn't start delayed_job running

```
bin/delayed_job start
```

Please also check you run

```
rails generate delayed_job:active_record
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Ok, just check if you have completed all the steps in the link I posted

Comment: That is indeed one of the 5-6 guides I followed

Answer (score 3):

If you are having this issue in your development environment even though you are using an adapter capable of asynchronous jobs like Sidekiq, make sure that `Rails.application.config.active_job.queue_adapter` is set to `:async` instead of `:inline`.

```
# config/environments/development.rb

Rails.application.config.active_job.queue_adapter = :async
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

in controller:

```
@user.delay.welcome_email
```

in your model

```
def welcome_email
 UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver_later(wait: 1.minutes)

end
```

Comment: I get the same error when I try this. There must be some sort of configuration issue, but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: just try it out no need of extra configuration you need to only install `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'` and `gem "daemons"`

Comment: i tested it locally working fine just install `daemons` i think you miss that

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what it was: I typically start my server and everything associated with it using a single shell script. In this script, I was running `bin/delayed_job start` in the background, and starting the server before `bin/delayed_job start` finished. The solution was to make sure `delayed_job start` finished *before* starting the server by running it in the foreground in my startup script.

Thanks everyone for all the help!